# GetType().InvokeMember command

Tags: powershell, powershell-remoting

I am trying to get the user list of RDP enabled group member from AD Computer OU. Somehow i am unable to get the full name details of users in other domain which i am not part of. The ADSPath shows the correct WinNT://DOMAIN/username. But full name details are blank. Any help will be appreciated. The full name details are correctly populated for domain which i am part of. The OU.csv file has the computer OU details and domain server details.

```
$Properties = "AdsPath","Name","FullName"

$Select = $Properties | %{  
  Invoke-Expression "@{n='$_';e={ `$_.GetType().InvokeMember('$_', 'GetProperty', `$Null, `$_, `$Null) }}"  
}

$OUData = import-csv c:\change\OU.csv
$OUexport = foreach($OU in $OUdata)
{
$OUpath = $OU.ou
$server = $OU.server

Get-ADComputer -filter * -Property * -SearchBase $OUpath -Server $server  | Select-object Name,DNSHostName,Description | ForEach-Object {

  $ComputerName = $_.Name
  $Description = $_.description
  $DNSHostname = $_.DNSHostName
  $Group = [ADSI]("WinNT://$DNSHostname/Remote Desktop Users")  
  $Group.PsBase.Invoke("Members") | Select-Object ([Array](@{n='Workstation';e={ $ComputerName }},@{n='Comp_Description';e={ $Description }}) + $Select)

} } 
$OUexport | export-csv c:\change\RDP_Enable.csv -NoTypeInformation
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try avoiding the Invoke-Expression here also enclosing a expression in single quotes doesn't expand the value:

```
$Select = $Properties | ForEach { @{n="$_"e={ $_.GetType().InvokeMember("$_","GetProperty", $Null, $_, $Null) }}}
```

Comment: The hash literal was incomplete.
At C:\change\Group.ps1:2 char:113
+ ... { $_.GetType().InvokeMember("$_","GetProperty", $Null, $_, $Null) }}}
+                                                                         ~
Unexpected token '}' in expression or statement.
    + CategoryInfo          : ParserError: (:) [], ParseException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : UnexpectedToken